# Adding a mailto link in a table cell (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, containers

so i am trying to figure out how to add a mailto link to a table cell when using a javascript container.

```
var users = [ {first_name: "Kaitlin", last_name: "Burns", age: 23, email: "kburns99753@usermail.com"}, {first_name: "Joshua", last_name: "Feir", age: 31, email: "josh319726@usermail.com"}, {first_name: "Stephen", last_name: "Shaw", age: 28, email: "steve.shaw47628@usermail.com"}, {first_name: "Timothy", last_name: "McAlpine", age: 37, email: "Timbo72469@usermail.com"},    {first_name: "Sarah", last_name: "Connor", age: 19, email:"SarahC6320@usermail.com"}
];

window.onload = function(){

var tableContainer = document.querySelector("#outputTable");

      var myRows = "";

      for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++){ 
            myRows += "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + users[i].first_name + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + users[i].last_name + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + users[i].age+ "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + users[i].email + "</td>" +
                      "</tr>";
      }

      tableContainer.innerHTML += myRows; 
};
```

So bascially after showing the code i have there, what i want to do is make the "email" part turn into a mailto link. How can i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
  var myRows = "";

  for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++){ 
        myRows += "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + users[i].first_name + "</td>" + 
                    "<td>" + users[i].last_name + "</td>" + 
                    "<td>" + users[i].age+ "</td>" +
                    "<td><a href=\"mailto:" + users[i].email + "\">"+users[i].email +"</></td>" +
                  "</tr>";
  }

  tableContainer.innerHTML += myRows; 
};
```

What we are doing here is adding the tag `<a href="mailto:themail@email.com">themail@email.com</a>` in the table.

Comment: Thank you!!! I can't even tell you how long it took me to try and figure this out, i guess i had the wrong syntax. Much appreciated